# Radio Buttons on Dart

Tags: radio-button, dart, dart-html

I'm trying to get the input for a radio button group but I can't find anywhere any examples or explanations of how to. All the ones I end up finding is deprecated or does not work :(

What I wan't is this:

The form will have 4 radio button groups and when submit is pressed I wan't to get the information from those 4 groups then do something with it. But I can't find anywhere a good way of doing it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried it and works

```dart
<input type="radio" id="r1" name="rate" value="Fixed Rate"> Fixed Rate
<input type="radio" id="r2" name="rate" value="Variable Rate"> Variable Rate
<input type="radio" id="r3" name="rate" value="Multi Rate" checked="checked">
```

.

```dart
main () {
  querySelectorAll('input[name=rate]').onClick.listen(clickHandler);
}

void clickHandler(MouseEvent e) {
  // two different ways of accessing the current value
  print('target: ${(e.target as InputElement).value}');
  print('checked: ${(querySelector('input[name=rate]:checked') as InputElement).value}');
}
```